# Getting 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, iteration

```
    cat_sums[cat] += value
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

My input is this:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'composed': [0], 'elated': [0], 'unsure': [0], 'hostile': [0], 'tired': [0], 'depressed': [0], 'guilty': [0], 'confused': [0], 'clearheaded': [0], 'anxious': [0], 'confident': [0], 'agreeable': [0], 'energetic': [0]})
```

And this is assigned to something called catnums

```
accumulate_by_category(worddict, catnums, categories)

        def accumulate_by_category(word_values, cat_sums, cats):
                for word, value in word_values.items():
                        for cat in cats[word]:
                                cat_sums[cat] += value
```

Now as far as I can tell, I'm not trying to iterate over an integer. I'm trying to add a value to another value inside catnums.

Is it possible that it is having trouble with the "cats" argument inside my accumulate_by_category() function?

Comment: please provide sample data for `worddict`, `catnums`, and `categories` to allow others to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 6):

Each of your values is a list.  The `+` operator, when applied to lists adds an *iterable* to a list.  It doesn't append a single value:

```
>>> [1,2] + [3,4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [1,2] + 3
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

It looks like you want to do `cat_sums[cat].append(value)`.

Answer (score 0):

`+`, when applied to lists, is concatenation. As BrenBarn said, `[1, 2] + [3, 4] == [1, 2, 3, 4]`.

But if you are actually trying to add numbers, as implied by your statement "I'm trying to add a value to another value inside catnums," then `append` will not do what you want.

If this is the case then the dictionary you show is probably incorrect. It's not a mapping of words to numbers; it's a mapping of words to lists of numbers (namely the list `[0]`). If you're trying to maintain a count of words, this is not what you want; you want `{'composed': 0, 'elated': 0, ...}` (note the lack of square brackets). Then the `+=` statement will work as expected.

If you cannot change the dictionary but simply want to change the number in the list, you can say `cat_sums[cat][0] += value`. However, it would make far more sense (if this is what you're after) to simply convert the "lists of zero" into plain old zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is getting this error inside a Django template …

When you do:

```
{% for c in cat_sums.keys %}
```

then, behind the scenes, the Django template language first tries a `cat_sums['keys']` lookup. Normally this would fail and Django would next look for a method. But since this is a `defaultdict`, the default value gets stored instead.

If the dict was created with

```
cat_sums = defaultdict(int)
```

What gets executed is:

```
for c in cat_sums['keys']:
```

i.e.,

```
for c in 0:
```

which quite rightly throws an error as the value `0` is not iterable.

Resolution? Pass `dict(cat_sums)` inside the context so the view gets a regular `dict`.