# Iterating over a dictionary's values not working (error is 'int' object is not an iterable)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting 'int' object is not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533650/getting-int-object-is-not-iterable)

So I am trying to add a value to a dictionary, based on some other code:

```
if not cat_sums.has_key(k):
        cat_sums[k] = 0
cat_sums[k] += value
```

The dictionary looks like this:

```
cat_sums =     defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'composed': [0], 'elated': [0], 'unsure': [0], 'hostile': [0], 'tired': [0], 'depressed': [0], 'guilty': [0], 'confused': [0], 'clearheaded': [0], 'anxious': [0], 'confident': [0], 'agreeable': [0], 'energetic': [0]})
```

And I am getting:

```
    cat_sums[k] += value
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Which makes sense, because cat_sums[k] = [0] for the first iteration, and [0] isn't an integer, it is a list. So then I tried this:

```
print cat_sums[k[0]]
```

To see what it would output, that is, to see if I should replace `cat_sums[k]` with `cat_sums[k[0]]`, however that gave me this:

```
[]
```

An empty list.

So how do I add to the value inside the dictionary cat_sums, iterating through every key? What am I doing wrong here?

Note, just to clarify, value is going to equal some integer value that is greater than or equal to 0 (though, that might change and negative integers may be allowed later on, but not yet)

Comment: I think you meant `cat_sums[k][0]` rather than `cat_sums[k[0]]`.

Comment: Don't use `has_key`, it's deprecated. Use `if k not in cat_sums:`

Comment: duplicate by the OP: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11533650/1025391

Answer (score 4):

This data structure is a bit confusing.  Perhaps you should try a different type of defaultdict:

```
cat_sums=defaultdict(int)
cat_sums[k]+=value
```

Of course, if you want to continually add elements to a list:

```
cat_sums=defaultdict(list)
cat_sums[k].append(value)  #same thing as cat_sums[k]+=[value]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to be using `defaultdict(list)` - it looks like you want to do:

```
dd = defaultdict(int)
for x in y:
    dd[x] += 5
```

On a side note: `if not cat_sums.has_key(k)` is Pythonically written as `if k not in cat_sums` - but this shouldn't be required using a `defaultdict(int)` if I'm understanding correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a number to a list. Try

```
if not cat_sums.has_key(k):
    cat_sums[k] = [0]
cat_sums[k][0] += value
```